# Node.js as a WebRTC proxy

Tags: node.js, webrtc, raspberry-pi3, uv4l

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with a camera module. I've installed uv4l, and that gives me the ability to access the camera stream from browser by creating a WebRTC connection from the browser. However, I want to have an extra layer between the client (browser) and uv4l WebRTC stream.

Is there a way to have a Node.js server, which would be a bridge between my client (browser) app and the uv4l stream?

Comment: Yes. Use Node to capture the stream from UV4L, do whatever you want with the stream, then forward the stream to the browser. Simple.

Comment: Well, I guess my first question really is - how do I capture/attach to the uv4l webrtc stream? I couldn't find any modules, which would create the rtc peer connection (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtcpeerconnection can not be used within node unfortunately).

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/troyth/node-raspicam/?

Comment: Haven't tried node-rapsicam yet, though I found a way to listen directly to the mjpeg stream from the uv4l. *:8080/stream actually exposes the actual mjpeg stream, that can be captured and piped with Node's request module easily. Thanks for you help.